# Magento upgrade from EE1.9 to 1.14

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade

Hello i have upgraded my magento EE 1.9 to 1.14.2.0.  My questions are

1) Upgrading directly from to major version is it okay? i don't any major issues so far in development. If i need to go for incremental approach to which version should i go?

2) Do i need to run any of the scripts in shell for my versions 
url_migration_to_1_13.php
url_migration_from_1_13_0_0_to_1_13_0_2.php
umt113_conflict.php
umt113_redirect.php

Comment: why you asking community about enterprise version issues - isnt it a bit weird??

Comment: Hi @Bharath Did everything worked well for you by not running url_migration_from_1_13_0_0_to_1_13_0_2.php?

Comment: @muk I don't remember this after all these years, but I remember there is the specific reason these scripts so I did not run as those issues are specific 1.13 version.

Comment: Thank you, I asked the question as I am going to upgrade one site from 1.10 to 1.14EE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you did the upgrade correctly and you **DON'T** have to do incremental upgrades

No you don't have to run the 1.13 upgrade scripts.